# VS 2015 crashes on opening .cshtml files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2015 Professional Edition and I have created a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project. When I first create the project, I can open files normally. However, simply closing VS and coming back to it later, it starts to crash on any attempt to open any cshtml file. I have uninstalled or disabled all extensions.

I've recreated the project twice and the same thing happens. This is the new project type with the JSON project file and all that. The older type seems to still work fine. It is the starting project right out of the box.

Comment: What's the error?  Do you get a pop up error message or is there anything in the Windows Event Log?

Comment: From the Windows Event Log: Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.24720.0, time stamp: 0x564ea97e
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.19045, time stamp: 0x56258f05
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0x40fc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d15de6e4b8b168
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: c665dca6-c9e1-11e5-ba75-3402861fbd2c

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed that change the behavior of the editor?  The easiest way to test this is to start Visual Studio in safe mode with `DevEnv.exe /SafetMode` and see if it crashes when opening the file.  If everything opens correctly in safe mode, then odds are that one of your extensions is misbehaving.

Comment: That was an excellent idea, Bradley, but it didn't make any difference. VS still crashed. I've run a repair on VS itself and it still happens.